# calculation in new column with if and else in pandas

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I am having below table

```
Particulars            DC    Amt
AA                     D      50
BB                     D      20
CC                     C      30
DD                     D      20
EE                     C      10
```

I require below output, if DC column is having "D" it should 
have same amount in "Amt" column and if DC column is "C" should 
multiply by (-1) with Amt amount.

```
Particulars            DC    Amt      TTL
AA                     D      50      50
BB                     D      20      20
CC                     C      30     (30)
DD                     D      20      20
EE                     C      10     (10)
```

Comment: Use `df['TTL'] = np.where(df.DC == 'D', 1, -1) * df.Amt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['TTL'] = np.where(df.DC == 'D', df.Amt, -1*df.Amt)
```

Comment: thanks - works fine

Comment: Can u send wirh if and else